# Identify mystery insect found in Boston, USA

Tags: species-identification, entomology

This insect is approximately 2.5mm.  It was recently observed in a Boston USA shower.  Do you know what type of insect this is?

[image]

Comment: This is a spider beetle (Coleoptera: Anobiidae: Ptininae); the focus does not let me go deeper at this time.